# How to modify string to have exactly ONE space in between each character in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a string that looks like:

```
dog cat hello   house apple    fork bird
```

I want to change the string to look like:

```
dog cat hello house apple fork bird
```

How would I achieve this using JavaScript and/or jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

`str = str.replace(/[\s]+/g, ' ');`

Comment: `\n` and `\r` are already in the `\s` set.